How to get dot and error bar plot (ggline without the lines) using ggpubr?
I have gone through a few tutorials on using ggpubr and I seem to be getting the hang of it. Instead of the ggline() plot, however, I want a dot and error bars plot only (i.e., what we get with ggline, but without the line). I usually make this graph using geom_point() + geom_bar() in ggplot but since ggpubr has its own plot functions I'm not sure how to use the stat_compare_means() and stat_pvalue_manual() to add the significance indicators to the type of plot I want.
Below is the code I'm using, but I'd like to make it so that I get a picture similar to the one here:

# Line plot of mean +/-se
ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", add = "mean_se")+
  stat_compare_means() +                                         # Global p-value
  stat_compare_means(ref.group = "0.5", label = "p.signif",
                     label.y = c(22, 29))  

For interested novices like me, here are two good pages on ggpubr:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/
https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-to-ggplot-facets/
I have tried using ggdotplot but that's more of a scatter plot instead of just giving one point for the mean for each condition.

ggpubr is fine for quick plots. But when it comes to customizing you will sooner or later reach limits. While there are some hacky ways, i.e. manipulating the ggplot object returned by ggline I would suggest to build your plot from scratch using ggplot2:
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(factor(dose), len)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", width = .1) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point") +
  theme_pubr() +
  stat_compare_means() + # Global p-value
  stat_compare_means(
    ref.group = "0.5", label = "p.signif",
    label.y = c(22, 29)
  )



that is amazing, thank you! I didn't know you could use the ggpubr functions with ggplot :)
